# Show image on link hover inside of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a scanned image of a receipt stored on the server to display after hovering on a link inside of a `table`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but was curious if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is what I have so far

**CODE**

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $(".preview").hover(function() {
     $(this).closest('img').show();
   }, function() {
     $(this).closest('img').hide();
   });
 });
```

```css
 .hide-image {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>01/14/16</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="preview">Lowes Receipt
          <img src="image-path/image.jpg" class="hide-image" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute;" /></a>
  </td>
  <td>$1235.96</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".preview").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('img').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-image {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>01/14/16</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="preview">Lowes Receipt
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="hide-image" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute;" />
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>$1235.96</td>
</tr>
```

You can try this method.

Answer (score 4):

Why not only use CSS for this simple task?

```css
.hide-image {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
}
.preview:hover .hide-image {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>01/14/16</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="preview">Lowes Receipt
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" class="hide-image" /></a>
  </td>
  <td>$1235.96</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try next() instead:</strike>

```
$(this).next('img').show();
```

Try find() instead:

```
$(this).find('img').show();
```

Comment: additionally you could just use jQuery's .toggleClass method.

Comment: the `img` tag is inside the `anchor` not next to it.

Comment: No, it is solely because of DOM traversing. I see this all the time. You would think closest() find the closest(), but it goes up the DOM tree. You need to seek down. My answer posted below should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Closest moves up the DOM. I have made this mistake before. Use find("img");

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unix102/yspbrwkd/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".preview").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('img').fadeIn();
     }, function(){
        $(this).find('img').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is this not excepted? This is the reason he is having an issue. read this to explain: https://coderwall.com/p/wxjljq/jquery-find-and-closest-are-your-best-friends

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be based on how jQuery's [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) works.

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "block")`, except that the `display` property is restored to whatever it was initially.

Since the `display` properties initial value is `none`, `show()` does nothing.

Here is another way to achieve the same thing while continuing to use jQuery. I also moved some inline styling into the css, for better practice:

HTML

```
<tr>
   <td>01/14/16</td>
   <td>
      <a href="#" class="preview">Lowes Receipt
      <img src="image-path/image.jpg" class="receipt-image" /></a>
   </td>
   <td>$1235.96</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.receipt-image {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100; 
}
.receipt-image.visible { 
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".preview").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest('.receipt-image').addClass('visible');
    }, function(){
        $(this).closest('.receipt-image').removeClass('visible');
    });
});
```

However, it's also possible to do this entirely with CSS, no jQuery or Javascript required! Simply remove the JS, and try out this CSS:

```
CSS

.receipt-image {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100; 
}
.preview:hover .receipt-image { 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Using only CSS would work if I was only displaying one receipt for the whole page but when the table is dynamically populated from a database, all the pictures for every link on the page would be shown on hover with CSS. I will have to go the jQuery path for this problem. I forgot about trying addClass and removerClass. I really appreciate the responses and I'll try in the morning and mark the correct answer